# php - сервер прерывает скачивание файла размером выше 1.2 ГБ

Tags: php, файлы, download

Когда питаюсь скачать файл размерностью 1.5 ГБ, он доходит к 1.2 ГБ и начинает скачку заново. Данная особенность только на продакшене.
Код скачки файла:

```
if (file_exists($file) === true) {
   if (ob_get_level()) {
       ob_end_clean();
   }

   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/zip');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Cache-Control: no-store');
   header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   readfile($file);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: А в логах что есть по этому поводу? Опять же, у вас тип содержания (Content-Type) application/zip - это верно для всех файлов?

Comment: Для данного типа файлов да, раньше стоял **application/octet-stream**, но проблема уже тогда была, вот делал перебор решений.

Comment: Рекомендую просмотреть рекомендации на англоязычном SO по [аналогичному вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786734/php-readfile-and-large-files). Хотя там ответа нет, но по крайней мере будут еще варианты для тестирования. Аналогично [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/downloading-large-files-reliably-in-php), и судя по нему, у вас могут быть проблемы с исчерпыванием свободной памяти.

Comment: Благодарю, буду тестировать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему!

Для скачки больших файлов можно подкрутить значения **max_execution_time** и 
 **memory_limit** как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176942/using-php-to-download-files-not-working-on-large-files), но данный подход плох тем что если файл постоянно растет настройки тоже должны соотносительно расти - не комильфо.

Нужное мне решения было описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80186/using-x-sendfile-with-apache-php), [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669093/x-sendfile-works-for-all-folder-and-not-just-xsendfilepath) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786734/php-readfile-and-large-files) по использованию X-Sendfile - для загрузки больных файлов.

Вкратце нужно установить библиотеку **mod_xsendfile.c** и подключить ее в **httpd.conf**, модифицировать php код в моем вопросе - примеры стандартной установки библиотеки для apache2 [тут](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) или [тут](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/20487/installing-apache-module-xsendfile-for-django), но мне нужно было через docker, момент з докером опускается если установка у вас в ручную.

**Dockefile**:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    apache2-dev

RUN wget -O /tmp/mod_xsendfile.tar.gz https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/mod_xsendfile-0.12.tar.gz \
    && mkdir /tmp/mod_xsendfile \
    && tar -xf /tmp/mod_xsendfile.tar.gz -C /tmp/mod_xsendfile --strip-components=1 \
    && cd /tmp/mod_xsendfile \
    && apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c \
    && rm -r /tmp/*
```

**httpd.conf**:

```
LoadModule xsendfile_module modules/mod_xsendfile.so

XSendFile on

XSendFilePath /path/to/download/catalog/
```

**php**:

```
...
header("X-Sendfile: $file"); // $file -> /path/to/file
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
ob_end_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

или в моём случае **Yii2**:

```
return Yii::$app->response->xSendFile($file); // $file -> /path/to/file
```